# JAX-RS unrmashalling with @XmlIDREF

Tags: java, json, jax-rs, unmarshalling

I have been looking into this issue for hours now, probably simple but I don't get it anymore:

I have an entity (Param) which is rendered to json via jax-rs. The entity references another entity (Step).
When writing / reading json, I dont want to see the whole step-entity but merely its id, so I use this code :

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Param implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Id
@GeneratedValue
long id;
@Column(name = "KEYNAME")
String key;
String value;
@XmlIDREF
Step step;  
}
```

Works perfectly for marshalling.

So any GET-request shows me something the following:

```
{id: 1,
key: "a",
value: "b",
step: 53
}
```

But when I post some param to the server, it cant map back the numeric id to a step-entity.

I need to provide the unmarshaller with a custom IDResolver. But how can I configure the unmarshaller???? The Jax-RS servlet is doing the marshalling for me. My code looks like that:

```
@Path("param")
public class ParamRepresentation {

  /**
   * Retrieves representation of an instance of ParamRepresentation
   * @return an instance of Param
   */
  @GET
  @Produces("application/json")
  @Path("{ID}")
  public Param getJson(@PathParam("ID") long id) {
    return (Param) ctr.find(id, Param.class);
}


@PUT
@Path("{ID}")
@Consumes("application/json")
@Produces("application/json")
public SuccessMessage updateStep(@PathParam("ID") long id, Param p) {
    ctr.update(p);
    ParamSuccessMessage sm = new ParamSuccessMessage();
    sm.setSuccess(true);
    sm.setParam(p);
    return sm;
}
}
```

so how can i configure the unmarshaller ?????

Comment: Good question. You've shown what you've tried and clearly explained where you think things are coming unstuck. Have a vote up.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've misunderstood the purpose of IDREF in XML schemas. It's there to allow you to refer to another element that is marked as an ID (i.e., with an `@XmlID` annotation in JAXB) *in the same document*. You can't use it to refer to an ID elsewhere in the world; for that you'd use a URI (possibly with a fragment identifier part). To do *those* in JAXB, you use:

```
@XmlElement    // You might be able to omit this part; it's here for clarity
@XmlSchemaType(name = "anyURI")
public URI exampleField;
```

You then need to work out whether the URI refers to something you know (i.e., resolve the URI and see if it points into yourself) and deal with the fragment identifier. Or do the more common trick of just using a string and don't worry about trying to magically hook everything up in the binding layer. (That works rather well in practice.)

Comment: +1 - @Florian - Here is a link to one of my blog posts that demonstrates what Donal Fellows said in his answer about IDREF:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/10/jaxb-and-shared-references-xmlid-and.html

Answer (score 1):

I've done a similar thing using Jersey and xml representations. I used an xml adapter to symmetrically map between the complete child element and the *partial* (just id) element.

I would annotate the Step entity in your Param entity as follows:

```
//javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(PartialStepEntityAdapter.class)
Step step
```

You would then need to define both the partial Step entity and the Adapter. The `PartialStep` would be identical to your original step class, but with just the id field.

The `PartialStepEntityAdapter` would map a `Step` to a `PartialStep` when marshalling and a `PartialStep` to a `Step` when unmarshalling:

```
//javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter
public class PartialStepEntityAdapter extends XmlAdapter<PartialStep, Step> {

    @Override
    public Step unmarshal(PartialStep partialStep) throws Exception {
        Step step = new Step();
        step.setId(partialStep.getId());

        return step;
    }

    @Override
    public PartialStep marshal(Step step) throws Exception {
        PartialStep partialStep= new PartialStep();
        partialStep.setId(step.getId());

        return partialStep;
    }
}
```

Hope that's some help.

Comment: Of course, you would have to find your own way to populate the rest of the entity after unmarshalling.